# ActiveMQ SSLException with Java 1.8.0_271-b09 client

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic

I'm running an ActiveMQ server with SSL authorization (via trust store).

The clients are written with Spring Boot and Camel. Each client has it's individual certificate.

When the **client's** Java version is updated to version `1.8_271` the SSL connection suddenly fails. This can be found in the ActiveMQ logs:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

After downgrading to `1.8.0_261` everything is back to normal.

And here is where it gets really weird: my ActiveMQ truststore currently contains 232 certificates. When I delete 2 of them (does not matter which one) the connection with the `1.8_271` client works again.

This really does not make any sense to me. How can the number of items in the server's truststore have anything to to with the client's Java version?

Some updates:

- I'm testing with the [ActiveMQ Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq)
- Changing the key store type from native JKS to PKCS #12 does not make a difference
- Using Java `1.8_271` on the server side behaves the same but shows a different error message:

  > java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u271-relnotes.html)

> **Improve Certificate Chain Handling**
> A new system property, jdk.tls.maxHandshakeMessageSize, has been added to set the maximum allowed size for the handshake message in TLS/DTLS handshaking. The default value of the system property is 32768 (32 kilobytes).

If your server requests client authentication, JSSE (edit) below 1.3 sends a CertificateRequest message specifying acceptable CA names derived from the certificates in your truststore, thus the number of certificates in your truststore affects the size of this message and may make it exceed the limit in which case the client rejects it (although I'm not sure I like using unexpected_message for this case).

Comment: Thank you very much. I just arrived at the same conclusion (message is too large because of acceptable client certificate CA names in the handshake) ;)

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to disable this.

In TLS 1.3 this information does not seem to be exchanged any more.

Comment: It's a system property; depending on your app(s) and environment there are usually ways to set system properties. The 1.3 protocol still allows this list, but you're right JSSE no longer sends it; I'm not sure why. If I have time, I'll download the source and look.